# Local geodesics in uniquely geodesic spaces

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, riemannian-geometry

A while ago I asked [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/848065/local-geodesics-in-uniquely-geodesic-spaces)
question in Math Stackexchange. Since I didn't receive an answer so far, I thought I'd ask it here.

Suppose $Y$ is a proper length space, where every pair of points $x,y\in Y$ can be joined by a *unique* length minimizing geodesic (i.e. global geodesic). Can there still be more than one *local* geodesic joining some two points, or is it necessarily so that the space is also uniquely locally geodesic?

If a uniquely geodesic space which is not uniquely locally geodesic exists, can one even cook up Riemannian manifold as an example?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Without further hypotheses it is easy to cook up a counterexample. Start with a standard torus of revolution, choose a point $p$ on the "outer" circle $\alpha$ and follow this circle until you reach the first conjugate point $q$ from $p$. It is well known that for points $x$ past $q$, the geodesic is no longer minimizing, and in fact there is a pair of geodesics $\beta$ and $\gamma$ joining $p$ to $x$. Now simply "trim" your manifold by removing everything outside the digonal region bounded by $\alpha$ and $\beta$. Here every point is joined to $p$ by a unique geodesic but for points $x$ on $\alpha$ beyond $q$, the geodesic $\alpha$ is no longer minimizing.

Comment: Aren't $p$ and $q$ joined by two minimizing geodesics?

Comment: No, $q$ is the "last" point with a unique minimizer.

Comment: I don't believe you :).  If $\beta_x$ is the minimizing geodesic joining each $x$ on $\alpha$ to $p$.  What's the limit of $\beta_x$ when $x$ converges to $q$?  Are you saying this goes to $\alpha$?  Proof or reference?

Comment: http://books.google.co.il/books?id=m11kEYr_V_AC&pg=PA188&lpg=PA188&dq=conjugate+point+on+torus+of+revolution&source=bl&ots=0aBOfLm3mZ&sig=bNJnHs677UCfHyKmZSF4suqU7M4&hl=en&sa=X&ei=Qh7qU7T9CrDa0QXV0oCgDA&ved=0CCoQ6AEwAg#v=onepage&q=conjugate%20point%20on%20torus%20of%20revolution&f=false

Comment: Thanks!  After looking at chapter 8 I believe you now :).

Comment: Thanks! that's indeed a nice example. I have a vague impression (but haven't worked out any details) that if the space has the additional property that every global geodesic can be uniquely extended to a (locally) geodesic line, then the local geodesics are also unique. If so, this would mean that one cannot have a (complete) Riemannian manifold as an example.

Comment: @Teri, Perhaps you should reformulate your question accordingly.